# dontenv (npm module) does not load correct .env file when executing node cli app from different folder

Tags: node.js, npm, dotenv, npm-link

I'm building a node CLI App that it's using dontenv to load some environment variables to connect to a mysql db.

I used

`npm link`

command to link to global and run the CLI app from anywhere.
The problem I'm facing is that .env file it's only loading when I run from the folder where the .env is.

[image]

Then if run same command from different folder ... I got error and this error it's because dontenv is not loading .env file properly

[image]

BTW this is how I'm reading the .env nothing special (as far i know)

in **config.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();

let config = {};

config.MYSQL_HOST = process.env.MYSQL_HOST
config.MYSQL_DB_PROFILES = process.env.MYSQL_DB_PROFILES
config.MYSQL_USER = process.env.MYSQL_USER
config.MYSQL_PASS = process.env.MYSQL_PASS
config.AWS_PROFILE = process.env.AWS_PROFILE

module.exports = config;
```

then I have an index.js (main entry point in package.json) that calls a process.js where I have

```
const config = require('./config');

...

async function getProfileData(clientdb) {
    let conn = mysql.createConnection({
        host: config.MYSQL_HOST,
        user: config.MYSQL_USER,
        password: config.MYSQL_PASS,
        database: config.MYSQL_DB_PROFILES
    });
    conn.connect();
```

And that's my problem :( (any help will be lot appreciated)

Comment: Is the `.env` file in the second directory that you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that when you run the app from outside the folder, it can't find the path to the .env file you need. You should try to specify the .env path in your config file like this adding:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '/full/path/to/your/env/file' })
```

See if that helps solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Tuaev. That was almost there, the problem was that. I fixed with:
`.config({ path: __dirname + '\\.env' });`

Thaks again.